# jQuery: fancyBox using multiple times with href?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a#a_test").fancybox({
        titleShow     : false,
        width:    400,
        height:   120,
        autoDimensions: false,
        overlayOpacity: 0.6,
        href: 'test.php' 
    }); 
});
</script>
<a href="#test" id="a_test">test</a>
```

This works fine.

Now i want to use this in a loop (in php), I am wondering if i need to include the settings all the time.

What will be different in each setting is the name(so it would be a_test1, a_test2, and so on) and the href (so it would be test.php?id=1, test.php?id=2 and so on).

I know i just can copy paste but it would be kind of sloppy code when i view the html, a bunch of document ready, a#a_test123, a#a_test2, a#test_3 settings, couldnt I just go with one setting, and then add the number of the loop id(e.g 1,2,3) to it. Something like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a#a_test<?php echo $number; ?>").fancybox({
        titleShow     : false,
        width:    400,
        height:   120,
        autoDimensions: false,
        overlayOpacity: 0.6,
        href: 'test.php?id=<?php echo $number; ?>'
    }); 
});
</script>
```

This would work too, if I made it in a function and call it each time e.g getFancy(1), getFancy(2).. but then it would still look and be slopp coding if you take a look in the output html, a bunch of document ready with diff. settings.

So is there a solution to do this smarter and simpler? So it gets something like a global setting for all the boxes.

Thank you a bunch in forward

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.fancybox_vid").each(function(){
       $(this).fancybox({
        titleShow     : false,
        width:    400,
        height:   120,
        autoDimensions: false,
        overlayOpacity: 0.6,
        href: 'test.php?id='+$(this).attr('rel')
      }); 
    });
});
</script>

<a class='fancybox_vid'  rel='1'>video</a>
<a class='fancybox_vid'  rel='2'>video</a>
```

Comment: .each iterates over whatever elements are found to match the selectior that preceeds it. in this case, for every A href link of the class fancybox_vid that jQuery finds, it performs the actions enclosed in the each. the $(this) references the particular instance being referenced in the loop.